# Disable null validation in ASP.Net 6 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-8.0

I have a really simple ASP.Net WebAPI project created in .Net 6. Given this controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task DoStuff(MyClass input)
{
   // snip
}
```

where `MyClass` looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
}
```

Posting this to the `DoStuff` method used to be allowed in previous versions of ASP.Net:

```
{
    MyData: null
}
```

Now however, it gives a 400 response unless I declare MyData as a `string?` instead of a `string`. My problem is that the `MyClass` class can not be altered, so I can't update `MyData` to be of type `string?`. Is there a way to disable the automatic null validation that ASP.Net does on MyClass properties? Adding `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` to the csproj file for the WebAPI project doesn't seem to do anything. My current csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1591</NoWarn>
    <UserSecretsId>MyProject</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AnotherProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: To me, this behaves as intended. You shouldn't be allowed to post null-values unless you declare the property as nullable, right? However, I see how this could be a problem if you upgraded a large project and need to refactor hundreds of endpoints. Apologies for being slightly off-topic.

Comment: Is `MyClass` part of the WebAPI project?

Comment: Yes @ChristophLütjen , that was the answer! MyClass was part of another project, I disabled nullable there as well and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a feature of C# 8, [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and in .NET 6 they are enabled by default. To turn it off, in your csproj file add this line `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>`. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also, if MyClass is in another project, add `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help David but this doesn't help, I'm still getting 400 responses. I'll update the question.

Comment: I think this feature is more a compile-time feature, while the question seems to have a runtime problem after upgrading to asp core 6.

Comment: @Oliver - if nullable ref types are enabled, asp will respect this when verifying requests and return 400 if a string is required but no value or null is provided.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen: And learned something new today. 

Comment: I updated this answer based on @ChristophLütjen 's comments. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you disable nullable in your **csproj**, it may cause warnings when you use the nullable operator(**?**). Adding the following code to your .editorconfig will allow you to use both methods (nullable or without nullable) without any additional warnings.

You can edit your **.editorconfig** file in your solution project.
Added these lines at the end of section **[*.{cs,vb}]**

```
#### Naming styles ####
[*.{cs,vb}]

# CS8618: Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8618.severity = none

# CS8601: Possible null reference assignment.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8601.severity = none
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach, if you do use nullable variables/properties/parameters, you will receive another warning when setting the nullable to disable.

To prevent it, and also disable the nullable warnings, I recommend to use the option "ANOTATIONS", this will show warnings when you specify that something is nullable and will not asume it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable or disable the checks differently per source file, e.g.

```
#nullable disable
```

See the [C# preprocessor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives?devlangs=csharp#nullable-context) for other options.