# Possible null reference return in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting this warning:

[image]

I want to remove this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when it does not find any item with the email address? it will simply return `null`.
So, you have to tell this method caller that it could also return `null` and in order to do so, you will simply have to make the return type nullable by appending `?` as shown below.

```cs
public User? GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    return _users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove following tag in .csproj file

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Answer (score -2):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71350179/disable-null-validation-in-asp-net-6-project) post, you can remove any warning having its code by adding these lines in your csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <NoWarn>8603</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also you may fix it using `editorconfig`

```
# CS8603: Possible null reference assignment.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8603.severity = none
```

Comment: ... defeating the purpose of Nullable Reference Types

Comment: @HansKeﬆing just giving what SO want.